# jscalc.io ROI calculator - hopefully easy

Tags: javascript

I am new to Javascript and I am trying to have an ROI calculator for a marketing campaign.  I got it to the point where there are no errors coming up, but no solution is appearing.  I am using the below script:

```
    'use strict';

     return { 

     output:[{
     OwnSIEM:((inputs.capitaloutlay)+(inputs.AnnualMaintenance*(    inputs.NumberofYears-  1))+((inputs.NumberofIndividuals*inputs.Salary)*inputs.NumberofYears)),
  BriteMSSP:(inputs.capitaloutlay+(inputs.NumberofYears*100000))},],
  totalsaving:(((inputs.capitaloutlay)+(inputs.AnnualMaintenance*(inputs.NumberofYears-1))+((inputs.NumberofIndividuals*inputs.Salary)*inputs.NumberofYears))-((inputs.capitaloutlay+(inputs.NumberofYears*100000))))
};
```

Comment: How are you invoking this JavaScript code? Where are you expecting to see a result?

Comment: please add four spaces before each codeline...